# How Can I resolve EOF Error when reading a line in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, eoferror

`and error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "solution.py:", line 3, in
str2 = input()
EOF Error: EOF when reading a line
```

I tried like this: 1st I recheck like I just change string input to integer input . just for testing that time also facing same error.

like I take input from user a = int(input())
but same thigs happen.

So, pls tell me how can I resolve these problem`

```
str1 = input()
str2 = input()
str3 = ''
for  I in str1:
    str3 =+I
for j in str2:
    str3 =+j
print(str3)
```

Comment: How are you providing the input? If you don't provide (at least) two lines to read, the best you can do is catch the `EOFError` tased by `input`.

Comment: You might want to just iterate over `sys.stdin` directly, with something like `for line in itertools.islice(sys.stdin, 2): for I in line: str3 += I`.

Comment: `=+ i` probably isn't what you want. It's `+=` to increment

Comment: But the eof error problem still continue @roganjosh

Comment: That may be so, but the chance that you wanted `=+` is vanishingly small, so you probably want to fix that anyway as an aside

Answer (score 0):

you just have to change str3 =+I into str3 +=I
and the same way to str3 =+J into str3 +=I

Comment: That's a typo unrelated to the question being asked.

Comment: I changed but the eof problem not solved.

Comment: @chepner Can u help me out? Can u tell me what I will change then get a output?